# How to select multiple options on HTML form in WSGI-Python

Tags: python, wsgi

I need to select multiple options from a HTML drop down from python code in WSGI,

Following is my html form,

```
    <form method=post>
    Please select names
    <select multiple="multiple" name="names" />
        <option>Name1</option>
        <option>Name2</option>
        <option>Name3</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type='submit' name=operation value='Next' />
</form>
```

Following is the code snippet on for WSGI,

```
if 'POST' == environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] :
try :
    request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
except:
    request_body_size = 0

request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
query_dictionary = urlparse.parse_qs(request_body)
params = {}
for k, v in query_dictionary.iteritems() :
    if k <> 'json' :
        params[k] = v[0]

retailers = params.get('retailers', '')
```

But my problem is when I select multiple options in HTML form, the "names" variable is only having one option. How to get all the selected options to python script ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use a framework. Writing raw WSGI is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Yes your correct. There is no straight forward way to get that.But need to do this using pure wsgi. And I found a way. Will put on answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution (Not a straight forward one).

in the query_dictionary dic the names list is coming only thing here to do is,

```
    for k, v in query_dictionary.iteritems() :
    if k <> 'json' :
        if k =="names":
            names = v
        params[k] = v[0]
    params["names"] = names
```

After that iterate through the names list